# jQuery dynamic div id with .each() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i created 5 div with class

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var numSlide = $('.slide_text').length;
   var slideLoop;
   var numSlideTemp = 1;
   for(slideLoop=numSlideTemp;slideLoop<=numSlide;slideLoop++){
      $('.slide_text').attr('id', 'slide_text_' + slideLoop);
   }
   $('#slide_text_3').html('OK!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div class="slide_text">Slide 1</div>
<div class="slide_text">Slide 2</div>
<div class="slide_text">Slide 3</div>
<div class="slide_text">Slide 4</div>
<div class="slide_text">Slide 5</div>
```

And i want to add attribut ID for each div, but after i run this script all ID set to **slide_text_5**.

I want result (id) like:

> - slide_text_1
> - slide_text_2
> - slide_text_3
> - slide_text_4
> - slide_text_5

in each div.

Is there something wrong with my script?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (slideLoop=numSlideTemp;slideLoop<numSlide;slideLoop++){
   $('.slide_text').eq(slideLoop - 1).attr('id', 'slide_text_' + slideLoop);
}
```

Use the `eq()` so you change only a single element that you want to change.  Otherwise you are changing them all.

This could also be written potentially as:

```
$('.slide_text').each(function(index, element){
    element.id = 'slide_text_'+ ( index + 1 );
});
```

Comment: Wow, I'm looking for a way for 1 hour, and you saved me in just 1 minute, thanks, tabarakallah.